# What is wrong with this REST API code?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, image, express, upload

The error I am getting with this code is

> Cannot POST /img/upload/'

Code:

```
 app.post('/img/upload/',[multer({ dest: __dirname+'/www/images/new/',
            rename: function (fieldname, filename, req, res) {
                    return filename + '_ORIGINAL';
            },
            onFileUploadStart: function (file, req, res) {
                     console.log(file.fieldname + ' is starting ...')
            },
            onFileUploadData: function (file, data, req, res) {
                     console.log(data.length + ' of ' + file.fieldname + ' arrived')
            },
            onFileUploadComplete: function (file, req, res) {
                     console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
            },
            onError: function (error, next) {
                     console.log(error)
                     next(error)
            }
    })]);
```

The controller request to this API is:

```
    var data = new FormData;
    data.append("file", files[0]);

     $http({
            url: 'http://52.25.181.109/img/upload/',
            method: "POST",
            data : data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.hide_u();
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.hide_u();
            console.log(data);
        });
```

The code executes with error. How do I correct this?

Comment: Are you requesting a different domain?

Comment: Is that all the error message says? or there is anything about cros-domain in it? @RohitKumar suggestion seems more likely since you are using ip address in that url.

Comment: Thats a post request I am making to aws database. Other GET request are working fine . I am getting problem only for this POST request.

Comment: Also a 404 not found error in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your header:  `headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}`
Multer caters only multipart requests. The route will not be valid for "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Form their site:

> Node.js middleware for handling `multipart/form-data`.

Update:
I set up a server. following should work, change the server handler:

```
app.use(multer({ dest: __dirname+'/www/images/new/'}));
app.post("/img/upload/", function() {console.log("request rec.")});
```

My test form was: `"<form enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">"`

Suggestion: try removing the header.

Comment: Added the header, it asked for boundary. I specified boundary and stil its the same problem.